# Поменять название в тулбаре

Tags: java, android

При смене фрагментов название всегда одно и тоже. Как можно менять название приложения в туллбаре при смене фрагментов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ваш текст");
```

Comment: блин пи переходе приложение остановилось и выделяет в логе эту строчку

Comment: Отредактировал, попробуйте теперь

Comment: Все заработало я убрал getActionBar()